# XML Serialization with C++ Boost: how to refer to the base class?

Tags: c++, boost, xml-serialization

When XML serializing a class with the Boost libraries, there is a point where we likely need to do it for a derived class. In this case, the manual [1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#nvp) instructs to include a reference to the base class:

> `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(my_base_class)`

However, if this class is inside a namespace, are we supposed to include the name of the class with, **OR** without the namespace?

For example, the base class is **Awesome::Foo** and a derived class from it is **Awesome::Bar**.

The question is, we should use, inside the implementation of the serialization of Bar, which of the following statements?

1. `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Foo)`
2. `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Awesome::Foo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would conclude from the Boost documentation that Case 1 is correct.

According to the documentation linked to [on Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#nvp)

they state with respect to `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(my_base_class)`:

> "Note that these macros must be used in the namespace of the class,
>   and without qualifying the namespace in the argument. "

They also give a code example using this macro at [this example link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/example/demo_gps.hpp).

Comment: Thanks for this quote, it is what I was looking for. For future reference: to use different namespaces, it is necessary to manually use the `boost::serializtion::make_nvp` function.